# Sort Matrix [3] [3] from one end to another

Tags: java

Im going to sort a [3][3] matrix from one end to another!

lets say i have following

```
6 7 1 
2 0 4
7 9 2
```

Sorted it should look like-->

```
0 1 2
2 4 6 
7 7 9
```

However i don't seem to figure out how to sort this correctly.. Im using bubble sort, but can only manage to sort one row at a time!

Should i convert the matrix into a single row array?

This is what i have:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {

  for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
   {
    if(a[i][k + 1] < a[i][k])
       {
         double temp = a[i][k];
         a[i][k] = a[i][k + 1];
         a[i][k + 1] = temp;
       }   
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why not sort all the elements and put it back into matrix form?

Comment: hmm yea! that is a possibility.. however i should do the sorting in a method :S so i think its not correct to do it like that.

Comment: You are not sorting the last element of previous row with first element of next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort all the elements and put it back into matrix. I know you do not want it that way. but I posted it if any one need it.

```
 public static int[][] sort(int[][] x) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                a.add(x[i][j]);

            }
        }

        Collections.sort(a);

        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                x[i][j] = a.get(k);
                k++;
            }
        }

        return x;
    }
```